# caused by android.app.fragment$instantiationexception unable to instantiate fragment

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

hey i have eror this is mya eror

i am creating example maps for android but i have problem this my problem

```
    10-13 06:31:26.923: D/AndroidRuntime(8754): Shutting down VM
10-13 06:31:26.923: W/dalvikvm(8754): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
10-13 06:31:26.963: E/AndroidRuntime(8754): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-13 06:31:26.963: E/AndroidRuntime(8754): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{fuad.viewmaps/fuad.viewmaps.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class fragment
10-13 06:31:26.963: E/AndroidRuntime(8754):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
10-13 06:31:26.963: E/AndroidRuntime(8754):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
10-13 06:31:26.963: E/AndroidRuntime(8754):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
10-13 06:31:26.963: E/AndroidRuntime(8754):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
10-13 06:31:26.963: E/AndroidRuntime(8754):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-13 06:31:26.963: E/AndroidRuntime(8754):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-13 06:31:26.963: E/AndroidRuntime(8754):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
10-13 06:31:26.963: E/AndroidRuntime(8754):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-13 06:31:26.963: E/AndroidRuntime(8754):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-13 06:31:26.963: E/AndroidRuntime(8754):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
10-13 06:31:26.963: E/AndroidRuntime(8754):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
10-13 06:31:26.963: E/AndroidRuntime(8754):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-13 06:31:26.963: E/AndroidRuntime(8754): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class fragment
10-13 06:31:26.963: E/AndroidRuntime(8754):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
10-13 06:31:26.963: E/AndroidRuntime(8754):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
10-13 06:31:26.963: E/AndroidRuntime(8754):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
10-13 06:31:26.963: E/AndroidRuntime(8754):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
10-13 06:31:26.963: E/AndroidRuntime(8754):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
10-13 06:31:26.963: E/AndroidRuntime(8754):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
10-13 06:31:26.963: E/AndroidRuntime(8754):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
10-13 06:31:26.963: E/AndroidRuntime(8754):     at fuad.viewmaps.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:12)
10-13 06:31:26.963: E/AndroidRuntime(8754):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
10-13 06:31:26.963: E/AndroidRuntime(8754):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
10-13 06:31:26.963: E/AndroidRuntime(8754):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
10-13 06:31:26.963: E/AndroidRuntime(8754):     ... 11 more
10-13 06:31:26.963: E/AndroidRuntime(8754): Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.google.android.gms.map.MapFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
10-13 06:31:26.963: E/AndroidRuntime(8754):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:592)
10-13 06:31:26.963: E/AndroidRuntime(8754):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:560)
10-13 06:31:26.963: E/AndroidRuntime(8754):     at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4709)
10-13 06:31:26.963: E/AndroidRuntime(8754):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
10-13 06:31:26.963: E/AndroidRuntime(8754):     ... 21 more
10-13 06:31:26.963: E/AndroidRuntime(8754): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.map.MapFragment" on path: /data/app/fuad.viewmaps-2.apk
10-13 06:31:26.963: E/AndroidRuntime(8754):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
10-13 06:31:26.963: E/AndroidRuntime(8754):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
10-13 06:31:26.963: E/AndroidRuntime(8754):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
10-13 06:31:26.963: E/AndroidRuntime(8754):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:582)
10-13 06:31:26.963: E/AndroidRuntime(8754):     ... 24 more
10-13 06:31:29.103: I/Process(8754): Sending signal. PID: 8754 SIG: 9
```

that's my problem

my code

MainActivity.java

```
package fuad.viewmaps;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView
```

(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

```
}
```

Activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="fuad.viewmaps.MainActivity" >



<fragment  
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.map.MapFragment"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="fuad.viewmaps"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <meta-data 
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyCuhxy29DShixyeHjzrB8NxfrQv9TCCZZI"/>


    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <!-- the following two permission are not required to use Google maps Android Api v2, 
    but are recomended -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 2):

Because of your  `android:minSdkVersion="8"`. So, you should change this

```
<fragment  
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.map.MapFragment"/>
```

to

```
<fragment  
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.map.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

and also change

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
```

to

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity
```

### Update:

Also you should add Google play service version as `<meta-data>` tag under `<application>` tag in your `manifest.xml`.

```
   <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Comment: Hello Manis, i'm fuad. i try change to your code but, still not running. help why.

Comment: I have tried, likte that in Google play service but not work and same problem... wait, can i ask your email, i will message you. becasue i'm make thesis. so please help me